# Hierarchical Listview QML

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I want to display hierarchical Data with a QML-Listview. This means that I have different Cpp datamodels, that have the following structure:

- Section 1

  - Subsection 1
  - Item
  - Item
  - Subsection 2
  - Item
- Section 2

The number of subsections is different in every model, so that I'm looking for a general solution to display that data in a flat list like that:

- Section 1
- Subsection 1
- Item
- Item
  ...

I'm using Qt 4.8.2 with Qt Quick 1.1.

What I figured out till now:

- The QML ListView cannot display hierarchical listmodels
- There are different solutions to display tree-structured extendable lists with multiple Listviews, but that's too complex for my models
- I can make my model flat by using a Abstract-Class insert different Object types in a flat list, but that would be a lot of work, cause I had to insert lots of loops

Till now I found one solution provided by blackberry cascades, but I can't use it because I have to run my application on Embedded Linux:

[Cascades Vegetables Data Model](http://blackberry.github.io/Cascades-Samples/vegetablesdatamodel.html)

At this moment I'm thinking about to write my own ListView with Cpp, but I would really like to avoid that because It will be a lot of work to implement that.

I'm new here at stackoverflow, so please let me know if I have to give you more informations.

Thank's in advance.

Quperman

**EDIT 05.08.2014:**

Temporary Solution:

Since It seems to be hard work for me to implement my own Cpp TreeView, I found another easier solution:

I created an abstract class AbstractItem with an attribute ItemType (enum), that has the following values:

- Item
- Section
- Subsection
- ...

What I now do is the following:
I inherit my Section and Item classes from my new class AbstractItem. Now I put QList into my QAbstractListModel and appended the items, sections, subsections... 
I can now provide different data in header and item by implementing the data() function with a switch over ItemType. depending on the ItemType I can do a reinterpret_cast to access the data.

Now I have a flat hierarchy that works for me. Sadly I can't use the class hierarchy, but at this moment it seems to be the fastest solution.

Comment: The lack of a TreeView is a major reason why I think QtQuick 1 and 2 suck, but anyway, the solution is: write your own TreeView, it is possible - I've written 2 already.

Comment: How did you write your TreeView? Did you write your own Cpp class or have you used QML to realize this? Thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: Cpp class, of course, QML is like JSON with some scripting ability added. A specification language mostly. Doing complex tasks in QML is usually not worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you really much, I will now try to implement it.

Comment: see that article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632795/QML-TreeModel-and-TreeView.

Comment: @folibis thanks for the link, I knew that link already. The problem with this solution is, that I have to add "levels" for each item. This is like the third point from my "figured out" section. That would make my hierarchical structure flat, but I would have to use multiple loops to do this in Cpp. That is going to slow my source-code down.

Comment: At this moment I'm working on a solution with my own DataModel, the same way Blackberry does it but I implement roleID's like in QAbstractItemModel (setRoleNames) too. I think using a QVariantList as IndexPath is a really "beautiful" and efficient solution.

Comment: @user1095108 Good Morning! Did you realize your Cpp Treeview with a delegate? I want to implement a delegate, but I don't really know/understand how to do this. It would be nice to get a little example or description how you realized that (I already know how to expose classes and models).

Comment: Yeah, there's a delegate, which is actually a `QML` component. You can instantiate a `QDeclarativeItem` from a `QDeclarativeComponent`. Of course instantiating objects brings some substantial overhead with it. You can alleviate some problems by caching objects you've already instantiated, but since one can zip from one end of a tree with a scrollbar, this is not a very effective solution.

Comment: I'm really interested in creating my own treeview, but I think it's too much work to implement it to my application. I found another solution, that is much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

15th May 2015 We got beta version of Qt 5.5. See its [features](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5). Take a deep breath... Now you can use `TreeView` component in QML!

Take a look at [snapshot for Qt 5.5 documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#details).

Comment: I already noticed that. I'm developing a mobile application without Qt Quick-Controls (Touch-Interface) because I had some performance issues with that controls on my embedded platform. I also want to use my own delegate's do display the data. But anyway I will try and hopefully be able to remove my model-hierarchy.